# PyQGIS: "with edit()" method breaks script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I am trying to calculate a new field in an attribute table using a QGIS expression in PyQGIS, and per the recommendations found [here](https://www.opengis.ch/2015/08/12/with-edit-layer/), I'm using the `with edit():` method. However, it is causing various troubles. For a start, this codeblock taken from the link above returns syntax error for `print repr(err)`.

```
try:
    with edit(layer):
        layer.addFeature(...)
        layer.updateFeatures(...)
except QgsEditException as err:
    print repr(err)
```

yields ↓

```
    print repr(err)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`print(repr(err))` doesn't return any error though, but now there's another problem. The script disappears from the Processing toolbox if I import QgsEditException. This is how the top of my script looks:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink,
                       QgsProcessingParameterField,
                       QgsField,
                       QgsGeometry,
                       QgsExpression,
                       edit,
                       QgsEditException)
from qgis import processing
```

I can solve that by not using QgsEditException. So I remove it from the imports, and I remove the `try...except...` statement in the codeblock and just stick with the `with edit():` unconditionally. But then the script crashes when I run it instead. I don't even get en error message, it just freezes and I have to force quit QGIS.

I am a mere beginner and this exceeds my understanding. Why is `with edit()` not working, an what should I do?

Comment: Is there really a ´QgsEditException` in existance?

Comment: @bugmenot123: Well, you're certainly right there isn't many google results on it. But the post I linked was posted by a company that works with the development of QGIS, although it was a few years ago. In case it is no more, how do I find out how to replace that code?

Comment: @joel, the post was 7.5 years ago, which is a very long time for actively developed software.  QGIS was in the 2.x days when the post was written, and QGIS switched to Python 3 with QGIS 3, which is why the print statement gives an error because it is Python 2 syntax.  In terms of `QgsEditException`, I don't believe it ever existed, and the post author probably meant to write `QgsEditError` but didn't try his own code to catch the mistake.

Comment: Furthermore, `.updateFeatures()` is not a method of `QgsVectorLayer`. It's worth mentioning that the existing [`updateFeature`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#:~:text=updateFeature-,Updates%20an%20existing%20feature%20in%20the%20layer%2C%20replacing%20the%20attributes%20and%20geometry%20for%20the%20feature%20with%20matching%20QgsFeature.id()%20with%20the%20attributes%20and%20geometry%20from%20feature.,-updateFields) method is not used in this context either (it is to overwrite the geometry and attributes of an exiting feature).

Comment: @bixb0012: Thank you for the info. I'm a Python beginner, couldn't have guessed this myself, I just trusted posts from the OpenGIS company to be accurate and correct. Problem solved with `print(repr(err))` and `QgsEditError` instead of QgsEditException. Thanks also @Matt for the heads-up, I won't be using `updateFeature` at all in this context.

Comment: Happy to help :) If you managed to get it working, you can post your solution as an answer to your own question. It will probably be helpful to future readers. (Just spotted a typo in my previous comment: exiting->existing)

Comment: OPENGIS are highly competent and respectable QGIS developers, the issue is that the post in question was very old and for a very different QGIS version :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @bixb0012 pointed out, the problem was that `QgsEditException` doesn't exist, but it should be `QgsEditError`, and that `print repr(err)` is old Python 2.x syntax, not supported in QGIS3 anymore, that's why it should be `print(repr(err))`. In addition, as @Matt pointed out `updateFeatures()` is also not supported anymore in the way that it's used in the code block above, because it's not a method of `QgsVectorLayer`. So a result that does in fact work would be for example this:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QVariant
from qgis.core import (QgsField,
                       QgsExpression,
                       QgsExpressionContext,
                       QgsExpressionContextUtils,
                       edit,
                       QgsEditError)

expression = QgsExpression('exampleexpression')
context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))
try:
    with edit(layer):
        layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField('new_fieldname', QVariant.Double)])
        layer.updateFields()
        for f in layer.getFeatures():
            context.setFeature(f)
            f['new_fieldname'] = expression.evaluate(context)
            layer.updateFeature(f)
except QgsEditError as err:
    print(repr(err))
```

Why my script crashed before was probably because of some other unforeseen blunder, but with this code, it works for me at least.